# Trying to draw 2 horizontal lines if Mouse is in a Component

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

I am struggling with a problem I have. I have this program which draws a face (w/ an optional hat). I am trying to get it so that if the mouse /cursor is inside the component, two extra little horizontal lines (c1,c2) are drawn to make it appear as if the eyes are closed. I am trying to use the mouse listener unsuccessfully and I was hoping someone may have some suggestions. Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Head extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
private Ellipse2D.Double e1;
private Ellipse2D.Double e2; 
private Ellipse2D.Double e3;  
private Ellipse2D.Double e4;
private Ellipse2D.Double e5;
private Rectangle2D.Double r1;
private Ellipse2D.Double r2;

private Line2D.Double c1;
private Line2D.Double c2;

private JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Hat");
private int i;

public Head () {
    this.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (600,600));
    e1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(200,200, 200, 300);
    e2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(255,285, 20, 10);  //eyes
    e3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(325,285, 20, 10);  //eyes
    e4 = new Ellipse2D.Double(285, 345, 30,30);
    e5 = new Ellipse2D.Double(265,410, 75, 20);

    r2 = new Ellipse2D.Double (90,175, 450,75);
    r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double (200,110,200,115);

    c1 = new Line2D.Double (255, 290, 275, 290 );   //horizontal lines across ayes
    c2 = new Line2D.Double (325, 290, 345, 290 );   //horizontal lines across ayes

    this.add(check);

     //a separate itemlistener

    class itemlistener implements ItemListener  {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent check){
            repaint();
        }
    }

    check.addItemListener(new itemlistener());



}

public void update(Graphics g) {  
    paint(g);
} 

//All the mouselistening methods. Im only using exit and entered

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    i= 0;

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    i = 1;
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

//this is a boolean method that is called is i==0 /mouse is inside to draw the lines

public boolean mouseInside(){
  return (i==0);
}


public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    // The first two lines are magic incantations to be explained in 209.
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; // convert to better Graphics2D
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); // looks nicer

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(e1); // draw the rectangle

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(e2); // draw the rectang

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(e3); // 

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(e4); // 

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(e5); // 

    if(check.isSelected()) {

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(r2); // 

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(r1); // 
    }

    //this is a method to draw the lines if the mouse is inside

    if (mouseInside()){
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(c1); // 

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(c2);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("ShapePanel demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    // Let's add two separate ShapePanel instances, just to see how it works.
    f.add(new Head());

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);  

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added any mouse listener to the panel. You need to add this line:

```
this.addMouseListener(this);
```

(it would be cleaner if the panel itself was not a mouse listener, and if you used a separate, inner class for the listener).

Moreover, the mouse listener changes the value of `i`, but doesn't ask the panel to repaint itself. So you need this line in the `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` methods:

```
repaint();
```

Also, note that the main method should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to construct and display the frame in the event disptach thread, and that you shouldn't override `update()`.